# rest call should return data as T if not loading and no errors

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, typescript-generics

when using fetch to post data in a react hook is it possible to infer that if loading is done, and there are no errors, data in not null?

```
type apiReturn<T> = {
  data:T | null,
  loading:boolean,
  error?: Error
}
type message = {
  msg:string
}
const apiPost = <T>(body:T):apiReturn<T> => {
  const [state, setState] = useState<apiReturn<message>>({data:null,loading:true,error:undefined})

  useEffect(()=>{
     const httpCall = fetch(url,{...postrequest, body:body}).then((resp) => {
      if (resp.parsedBody === undefined){
         setState({ data:null,loading: false, error:new Error("Oops... Something went wrong!") });
      }
      setState({ data:response.parsedBody,loading: false });
     
  },[fetch,setState])
  return state
}
const usePost = (data:message) => {
  const apiresponse = apiPost(data)
  if(!apiresponse.loading && apiresponse.error === undefined)
    //Possibly undefined, but should be defined as everything went okey
    const test:message = apiresponse.data
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions):

```
type ApiReturn<T> = {
  loading: true,
} | {
  loading: false,
  error?: undefined,
  data: T,
} | {
  loading: false,  
  error: Error,
  data?: null,
}
type message = {
  text: string
}
const apiPost = <T extends object>(body: T): ApiReturn<T> => {
  return null! // Implementation here
}


const usePost = (data: message) => {
  const apiresponse = apiPost(data)
  if (!apiresponse.loading && apiresponse.error === undefined) {
    const test: message = apiresponse.data
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAQSgSwEozAVwE4DsA8AKgHxwC8cA3qHHADYD2AhgCbK4DmAXHGNpjAA0oAL5wAPlRr1mbTjwBmTOgGch0mNmwNsAfh6ZcLGAvYwWwkLRZMwTHoUtjJ1KzNbtucJaqG0NWjo8AKKB2JbWtkz6cLiYdHROoJCwcAC2MCoqTBzwFK60YDAAHmA8KnyeoqAAxgy4FXBMKAAKDI0URHAlRUYqcAwARgBWMDVgxAAUgwwsEA4AlDxIaBg4BCTkpAVw2Gt4sfF0AIRwAPRncACSaVB0MBm4dmDI9XAAFpow1SCgtfWNTBqNodOCTGx2HgZLI5GALLZSNx1BpgJooPYqKAAvJo5AgsDgqILaTIBRg47NZAYrENGAAOkYHk4cAAZCzcdTsXTNNpsOQyBRDMZTLhzPCdrRkY0ihUoZlsrlyBzMjS1HSIUxpCJREA)